# Does taking someone's answer from discussion in comment section and repost it as an answer normal?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

I was in a discussion with a user with his problem in his question, but the user's problem was solved using my advice which appears in the comment section.

After this, the user takes my advice and post it as an answer to his question!

So, is this something normal or should I do something about it (like flagging his answer?)?

Comment: What is your objection to this? Did they give you credit for the suggestion in the answer?

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63403489/3266847)?

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, he did

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes.

Comment: I think it will be better to ask the user to make his comment into a proper answer. If he doesn't want to, then it will be okay to do it?

Comment: Yes OP could have asked you to do that, but they aren't required to do so. All they _need_ to do is to give credit to the original comment writer.

Comment: The real question is, why didn't **you** provide an answer in the first place?